# is it enough to determine segment for two IP addresses with different netmasks by bitwise AND?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, segment

I read about the rules of how hosts communicate with each other. Let's say hostA and hostB. hostA gets its own network ID by bitwise-and its ip address and its mask, then gets hostB's network ID by bitwise-and hostB's ip address and hostA's mask. If the results are the same, then they are in the same network segment.

Assuming hostA doesn't know hostB's MAC address: if they are in the same segment, hostA sends ARP request to switch and finally gets hostB's MAC address; if they are not in the same segment, hostA uses gateway MAC address as destination MAC address and hostB's ip address as destination ip address, and send the frame to gateway. That is how it works.

I can understand when the two hosts' ip addresses are like 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.2/24. But what happened when they are like the following:

If hostA is 192.168.0.1/16 and hostB is 192.168.1.1/24, hostA gets its own network ID:

```
192.168.0.1 & 255.255.0.0 -> 192.168.0.0
```

then hostA gets hostB's network ID:

```
192.168.1.1 & 255.255.0.0 -> 192.168.0.0
```

So hostA thinks they are in the same segment. But for hostB, hostB gets its own network ID:

```
192.168.1.1 & 255.255.255.0 -> 192.168.1.0
```

then hostB gets hostA's network ID:

```
192.168.0.1 & 255.255.255.0 -> 192.168.0.0
```

So hostB thinks hostA in a different segment.

How do they communicate in this case? For example, they don't know each other's MAC address, hostA uses one way to find hostB and hostB uses another way to find hostA?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake because you have overlapping networks. You cannot configure that in a router. You must have consistent addressing, and you will have problems communicating until your IP addressing is corrected.

Comment: what do you mean by "overlapping networks"? Could you be more specific? Do you mean the example I gave can't be real?

Comment: If you mask the network addresses with their respective masks, they resolve to the same network address: `192.168.0.0`. You could not configure a router with two interfaces that resolve the same network. If they are on the same LAN, then Host B thinks Host A is on a different network, and any traffic sourced at Host B destined for Host A will be sent to Host B's configured gateway (router). Routers route between networks, not from a network back to the same network. In any case, you have a configuration problem that must be resolved. This is covered at [networkengineering.se].